# sites/simpletest permissions are set to 777, but still "permission denied" error

Tags: 8, testing

I am running a WebTestBase test and getting the following warnings:

[image]

But the files and folders within sites/simpletest are set to 777. Drupal does already write within this folder during the test execution. What is the problem here?

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2867042