# Running functional test, the actual tests pass, but PHPUnit throws an error about rmdir() for a simpletest directory

Tags: 8, testing

Running from CLI... my tests all pass, but the framework itself is throwing an error when trying to clean up a directory. I am not sure what it is coming from, and how to fix it. The directory sites/simpletest has 777 on it.

```
vagrant@local:/var/www/mysite/docroot$ ../vendor/bin/phpunit -c ../phpunit.xml modules/custom/netforum_auth
PHPUnit 4.8.35 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E.......

Time: 24.07 seconds, Memory: 8.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) Drupal\Tests\netforum_auth\Functional\AuthenticationTest::testAdminUserUsesDrupalAuthentication
rmdir(sites/simpletest/52528722): Operation not permitted

/var/www/mysite/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileSystem.php:256
```

I'm stuck.

edit: [possibly related](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215769/sites-simpletest-permissions-are-set-to-777-but-still-permission-denied-error)

edit 2:

Running the command with `sudo` shows no error. Why? I tried adding vagrant to the web data user group, no difference. Only `sudo` works. This is in DurpalVM, Drupal 8.3.5.

edit 3:

Per the docs:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

Therefore, this should work:

```
sudo -u www-data -E ../vendor/bin/phpunit -c ../phpunit.xml
```

However it works sometimes, and not others. 50% success rate at the moment, with the same file permissions error.

edit 4:

Similar yet different error:

```
1) Drupal\Tests\netforum_auth\Functional\AuthenticationTest::testAdminUserUsesDrupalAuthentication
Exception: Warning: file_put_contents(sites/simpletest/61504822/files/php/twig/597a393cb6709_form-element.html.twig_dJcTIbdx1y7B0dbOtEyyZSSZ1/.htaccess): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Drupal\Component\PhpStorage\FileStorage->ensureDirectory()() (Line: 122)
```

Comment: Did you check the directory the error is referring is empty?

Comment: It doesn't tell me which directory it is referring to. It looks like I have run the gamut here for creating, removing, and writing to the simpletest folder created on the test run. The kicker is, sometimes it runs fine, and other times it throws error, with the very same command.

Comment: All the test dirs it creates are empty in the end, but not removed.

Comment: Try setting the sites/simpletest directory ownership: `chown www-data:www-data sites/simpletest`

Comment: I have done this and I have also added the vagrant user to the group, no change.

Comment: In my DrupalVM the owner is 501:dialout

Comment: when you are running your test, check out the permissions it writes within sites/simpletest ... i kept doing an "ls -la sites/simpletest" when running the test and you can see the directories being created in real time and then investigate what user is actually making the folder

Comment: Yeah they start out as writeable, and by the end they are no longer writeable (watching perms)

Comment: Well I can just tell you what I did. I changed the ownership to apache:apache of my sites/simpletest; then I ran my test as the apache user and it worked.

sudo -u apache ./phpunit -c ../../core/phpunit.xml ../../modules/contrib/examples/hooks_example/tests/src/Functional/HooksExampleTest.php

Comment: It is not allowing me to change ownership, even with sudo. `chown: changing ownership of 'simpletest': Operation not permitted`

Comment: Must be a weird DrupalVM permission thing? Not sure...

Comment: Yeah, I have posted over there.